# Uploading video to Facebook using FB SDK on iOS, removes orientation. How do I fix it?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, video, sdk

I can upload to facebook just fine using the facebook iOS SDK.  However, a video shot in the app (our own app) in portrait orientation ends up in landscape on facebook.

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];      
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);      
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

Above is the code that converts the video file to a NSData file that is included in the FB upload request.  I imagine that's where i'm losing the orientation, but i can't find a solution.  Any help out there?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following Url

[iphone ShareKit with Video upload for facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619769/iphone-sharekit-with-video-upload-for-facebook/11408084#11408084)