# How to share video on facebook programmatically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I used the following parameter but it is not working and instead the image is uploaded to the `facebook`.I stored the video in bundle and referenced it by storing in `AVAssest` and then passed the object of `avasset` as parameter...
but it is not working !!! can any one suggest me the proper and perfect way to do it.
I did lot of R&D but didn't get much fruitful.Please help me out to solve this.Thanks in advance....

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"Upload video text", @"name",
                                       @"Video 001", @"caption",
                                       fbMessage, @"description",
                                       @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQcVllWpwGs", @"link" , image, @"picture",
                                       avAsset, @"source",
                                       @"video",@"type",
                                       nil];
```

Comment: Try with facebook graph api....See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933550/how-to-upload-video-on-facebook-using-facebook-sdk-3-1-on-ios/14933695#14933695

Comment: Refer the following Url

[Click this and see how to upload and  share video in Facebook using share-kit  ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619769/iphone-sharekit-with-video-upload-for-facebook/11408084#11408084